# Matlab: How to establish a relationship between two elements belonging to the same table?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, compatibility

I have three matrix like these:

```
categories1 =

     1     2   NaN
     3   NaN   NaN
     4   NaN   NaN

categories2 =

     1     2     3   NaN
     4     5     6   NaN
     4     5     6     7
```

that put beside give:

```
all_categories =

     1     2   NaN     1     2     3   NaN
     3   NaN   NaN     4     5     6   NaN
     4   NaN   NaN     4     5     6     7
```

Then, I have two vectors like:

```
obj1 = [4 2 1]

obj2 = [2 3 5]
```

How can I establish a condition that permits a certain operation between an element of `obj1` and one of `obj2`, if and only if their correspondent category belong to the same line in all_categories? In other words, I would like to start a if block in the form:

```
if (a specified element of array `obj1` is on the same line of another specified element of the array`obj2`)
    do something
end
```

For instance, the condition would be verified in case of `obj1(2)` and `obj2(1)`, because their correspondent value are both on the 1st line of `all_categories`).

Basically, I am trying to implement the condition that only if there is compatibility between and object belonging to a certain category and another object belonging to another category than an operation can happen.
Hope this has not been too long to explain. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I solved this issue. Just in case, for those interested, I did:

```
[row_c1,col_c1]= find(categories1==1);
[row_c2,col_c2]= find(categories1==2);
[row_c3,col_c3]= find(categories1==3);
[row_c4,col_c4]= find(categories1==4);
clear col_c1 col_c2 col_c3 col_c4);
all_rows_c = padcat(row_c1,row_c2,row_c3,row_c4);

[row_v1,col_v1]= find(categories2==1);
[row_v2,col_v2]= find(categories2==2);
[row_v3,col_v3]= find(categories2==3);
[row_v4,col_v4]= find(categories2==4);
[row_v5,col_v5]= find(categories2==5);
[row_v6,col_v6]= find(categories2==6);
[row_v7,col_v7]= find(categories2==7);
[row_v8,col_v8]= find(categories2==8);
clear col_v1 col_v2 col_v3 col_v4 col_v5 col_v6 col_v7 col_v8;
all_rows_v = padcat(row_v1,row_v2,row_v3,row_v4,row_v5,row_v6,row_v7,row_v8);
all_rows_v = all_rows_v';


for i=1:length(obj1)
    for j= 1:length(obj2)
        ind1 = obj1(i);
        ind2 = obj2(j);
        if any(all_rows_c(ind2) == all_rows_v(ind1,:))
            2+2 %test
        end
    end
end
```

In this way, the result of the test (4) is displayed exactly 7 times, i.e. the number of times that there is a compatibility in the table.
Hope this could be useful to someone. I am sure there are faster and more elegant ways of doing it.